# Displaying multi-dimensional array nicely

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently making a personal site, that can show movies/shows i own nicely.

I have created a multidimensional array, that contains
Array -> Season -> Episode(info)

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [episode] => 1
                    [ep_id] => 1
                    [ep_title] => Days Gone Bye
                    [ep_runtime] => 67 min
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [episode] => 2
                    [ep_id] => 14
                    [ep_title] => Days Gone Bye
                    [ep_runtime] => 67 min
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [episode] => 2
                    [ep_id] => 12
                    [ep_title] => Days Gone Bye
                    [ep_runtime] => 67 min
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [episode] => 3
                    [ep_id] => 13
                    [ep_title] => Days Gone Bye
                    [ep_runtime] => 67 min
                )

        )

)
```

Code used:

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_object())
{
    $season = $row->season;

        $episodeArr[$season][] = array(
            'episode' => $row->episode,
            'ep_id' => $row->ep_id,
            'ep_title' => $row->ep_title,
            'ep_runtime' => $row->ep_runtime
        );
}
```

Now i want to loop it, so i can disply it nicely with html.
Just like this:

```
<div>
    <p>Season: 1</p>
    <div>
        <a href="overview.php?id="1">
        <p>Episode: 1</p>
        <p>Title: </p>
        <p>Runtime: </p>

        <a href="overview.php?id="2">
        <p>Episode: 2</p>
        <p>Title: </p>
        <p>Runtime: </p>


    </div>
</div>
    <div>
    <p>Season: 2</p>
    <div>
        <a href="overview.php?id="3">
        <p>Episode: 1</p>
        <p>Title: </p>
        <p>Runtime: </p>

        <a href="overview.php?id="4">
        <p>Episode: 2</p>
        <p>Title: </p>
        <p>Runtime: </p>


    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried following various tutorials with foreach loops. But i ended up printing all the info in a single string. Which isn't preferable.

```
foreach ($episodeArr as $seasons)
{
    foreach ($seasons as $episodes)
    {
        foreach ($episodes as $key => $episode)
        {
            echo $key . $episode;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will print all the info in a single string. Only your single string should look like the HTML code in your post.

So let's think of it this way, you want this HTML for every episode.

```
<div>
    <a href="overview.php?id="'. $episode['id'] .'">
    <p>Episode:</p>
    <p>Title: </p>
    <p>Runtime: </p>
</div>
```

And you want this wrapping part for every season:

```
<div>
    <p>Season:</p>
    ...
</div>
```

Now think about your loops like this:

```
foreach ($episodeArr as $seasons)
{
    // this works once for each season
    foreach ($seasons as $episode) // note that it's not $episodes but $episode
    {
        // this works once for each episode
        foreach ($episode as $key => $field) // note that it's not $episode but $field
        {
            // this works once for each field of an episode
            echo $key . $episode;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to echo the wrapping part for each season:

```
foreach ($episodeArr as $seasons)
{
    echo '<div>';
    echo '    <p>Season:</p>';

    //        ... (The inner part)

    echo '</div>';
}
```

The inner part for each episode:

```
foreach ($episodeArr as $seasons)
{
    echo '<div>';
    echo '    <p>Season:</p>';

    foreach ($seasons as $episode) // note that it's not $episodes but $episode
    {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '    <a href="overview.php?id="'. $episode['id'] .'">';
        echo '    <p>Episode:</p>';
        echo '    <p>Title: </p>';
        echo '    <p>Runtime: </p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now you need to fill other fields in the code. Let's put them in their fitting places in the loops:

```
foreach ($episodeArr as $seasons)
{
    echo '<div>';
    echo '    <p>Season:</p>';

    foreach ($seasons as $episode) // note that it's not $episodes but $episode
    {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '    <a href="overview.php?id="'. $episode['id'] .'">';
        echo '    <p>Episode: '. $episode['ep_id'] .'</p>';
        echo '    <p>Title: '. $episode['ep_title'] .'</p>';
        echo '    <p>Runtime: '. $episode['ep_runtime'] .'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now your code doesn't place newlines between HTML tags so the output won't be readable. You fix this by placing a newline (`"\n"`) accordingly like this:

```
echo '<div>'."\n";
```

Note that I have been using `echo` for every line I print to be able to explain what I'm doing easily. There are more convenient ways to output in php. You may want to look up "string concatenation in php" and "heredocs". You should be able to find the info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Well, I guess I was 3 minutes late

Comment: Thanks anyway, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like i was able to answer my own question after all.

For anyone curious, this was my solution:

```
foreach ($episodeArr as $key => $val)
{
    print "Season: $key <br>\n";
    foreach ($val as $key2 => $episodes)
    {
        echo 'ep_id ' . $episodes['ep_id'] . '<br>';
        echo 'episode ' . $episodes['episode'] . '<br>';
        echo 'ep_title ' . $episodes['ep_title'] . '<br>';
        echo 'ep_plot ' . $episodes['ep_plot'] . '<br>';
        echo 'ep_poster ' . $episodes['ep_poster'] . '<br>';
        echo 'ep_runtime ' . $episodes['ep_runtime'] . '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

Quick and dirty, but it works.